# c# Add listView items from another form

Tags: c#

I am trying to **add items in a listView from an antoher form** but I don't no how I can do that. I have try this but it gives an error.

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Local_Host
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _Form1 = this;
        }

        public static Form1 _Form1;

        public void AddItem(object value)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Form2

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1._Form1.AddItem(textBox1.Text); //error

    }
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @eddie_cat Form1 is the class name and he is calling the _Form1 static variable of the class Form1. Better wait for an explanation of what is not working

Comment: It has some invalid arguments

Comment: probably you never run the constructor of form1 and getting a NRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the function

```
 public void AddItem(object value)
 {
     listView1.Items.Add(value);
 }
```

you pass an object to this function and try to add it to the ListViewItemCollection, but there is no [overload of the Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) of the ListViewItemCollection that accepts an object

Change it to

```
 public void AddItem(string value)
 {
     listView1.Items.Add(value);
 }
```

This will solve the immediate compilation problem, but you will have hard time working with that static variable. If your plan were to pass values from form2 to form1 it is better that you keep the  created instance of form1 and use it to pass values through the AddItem method otherwise you will end to add that values to other instances of the Form1 (the latter instance created will receive the new string)

Comment: Yes that solve the immediate problem, but you better plan for another method to pass values from form to form because that static variable is very dangerous

Answer (score 0):

Instead pass the textbox value to Form1 constructor like

Form2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1(textBox1.Text);
    frm.show();
}
```

Then in Form1 add the value to your listview like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(string listview_val)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.listView1.Items.Add(listview_val);
    }
}
```